# problem at passing params in react routing when you use "?" and put something after it

Tags: reactjs, api, parameters, react-router

i know the question may seem a little confusing so let me explain it,
I have an item page that loads items based on it's limitation and gives u,next and previous page `url`,
and that `url` is something like this,

```
url = "https://api.sth.com/v1/all-tours/NY?page=1"
```

and my route to that component is something like this

```
<Route path="/Tours/:Tourtype/:city" component={MainPage}>
</Route>
```

and here is the Link i have to that page

```
<Link to={`/Tours/all-tours/${SearchResult.slug}?page=1`}>
</Link>
```

and here is how i call the api in my component

```
axios.post(`http://api.hichhop.com/v1/all-tours/${this.props.match.params.city}`, options)
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log(response)
});
```

but the problem i'm facing is that in `this.props.match.params.city` is for example just like this

```
this.props.match.params.city= "NY"
```

instead of it being something like this

```
this.props.match.params.city= "NY?page=1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using `'react-router-dom'`. So I also assume you have access to location. Try the following: `this.props.location.search`

When you open `url = "https://api.sth.com/v1/all-tours/NY?page=1"` , you would be able to retrieve the following string: `"?page=1"`. To the the NY parameter, you will have to continue using `this.props.match.params.city`